# How to access system files with node.js/electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, electron

I am trying to read system files from a mac using electron/node.js, currently how i do it is.

```
fs.writeFileSync(`/Users/${os_username}/sync_message_images/chat.db`,fs.readFileSync(`/Users/${os_username}/Library/Messages/chat.db`));
```

But i keep on getting a EACCESS error, I Believe this is because it is a system file because i cannot copy it from the terminal or with python without root. Is there anyway I can grant the application root access? Even if the user has to type in there password at launch that is fine.

I even tried with sudo-prompt and i continue to have the same issue.

Comment: *"Is there anyway I can grant the application root access?..."* - Well I certainly hope not! Making processes "root" is never the solution. `/Users/${os_username}/` does not look very portable between different OS's to me. Plenty of material on that topic you can look for. Bottom line is the process is likely running with different permissions than the space it is trying to access or that path simply does not exist. FIX THAT PROBLEM, instead of looking for the "hammer" that changing to "root" is.

Comment: I only need it to work on macOS.

Comment: I don't care. Still no excuse to write bad code. But if you have an `EACCESS` then that's the systems way of saying *"You don't belong here!!"*. So if you're asking a process with different perms to access something it's not granted access to, then that's expected. Change to "root" is not the solution. Change 1. The perms the process is run under. Or 2. Allow group access to a location where the process is part of that group. Also FYI every OS I know of has an accessible `$HOME` somewhere.

Comment: Actually this seems to be an unrelated issue due to the newest version of macOS. If anyone else has this problem you must give the application full disk access. Do this by going to settings > Security > Privacy > Full disk access > Grant you .app full disk access.

Comment: @NeilLunn there are some cases where root access is the solution; for example accessing GPIO pins (via /dev/gpiomem) on a raspberry pi can only be done with root access. For me the whole point of using Electron is to allow creating a desktop app built with React etc that can have root access to some devices on the system.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this seems to be an unrelated issue due to the newest version of macOS. If anyone else has this problem you must give the application full disk access. Do this by going to settings > Security > Privacy > Full disk access > Grant you .app full disk access.